Infinite limsup and bounded
Suppose I have a sequence $\{\theta_t\}_t$, I can derive from other parts of the proof that $\lim\sup_t\theta_t = \infty$ and $\lim\inf_t \theta_t = -\infty$. I wonder given the previous fact, is it possible that we still can have bounded sequence $\theta_t$. If yes, what are the conditions?
This may be related but $\theta_t$ is actually a Markov chain and $V(\theta_t(i)) = p(i) (1-p(i))$ meaning the variance becomes smaller as $p(i)$ goes to either $0$ or $1$, so the $\theta_t$ may be bounded. However, I am not really sure.

No, if $\lim\sup_t\theta_t = \infty$ the sequence is not bounded.

$\lim\sup_t \theta_t = \infty$ is already sufficient to conclude that the sequence is unbounded. With regards to the variance decaying, this does not really effect the boundedness of the sequence (although I am a bit confused by your notation $\theta_t(i)$ and $p(i)$). For example, set $p = 1$ and consider the "random" walk $S_n = \xi_1 + \ldots +\xi_n$ where $P(\xi_i = 1) = p$. Then the variance of $S_n$ is zero but $S_n \rightarrow \infty$.
